# apxs2 not found or not a directory

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, apxs2

I'm trying to compile PHP 5 in ubuntu server, it's a larger explanation the why I need a compilated version and just download and install.
So, the thing is that in the process I get this error:

```
Can't exec "a2enmod": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apxs2 line 578.
'a2enmod php5' failed
```

So , I went to that directory and there's a file called `apxs2` so whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /path/to/binary binary-name
```

in your case binary-name is a2enmod, to determine your path try to run:

```
locate a2enmod
```

This file should be in /usr/sbin directory

Comment: Solved my issue installing PHP with PHPBrew, thanks for that